# web part view without the selection button

Tags: web-part, list-view

I am trying get a look and feel like central admin resource list view wp. I created exactly same type list and populated. But my list view does not have bullets and when I hover over the link it gives me the selection option which I dont need for this view. Please suggest.

[image: Resource list view wp from central admin]

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the list on a page. Go and edit the Web Part and as View select <Summary view>:
[image]

Comment: PJ: I looks good but then when I publish the setting goes away and I dont get the view any more.